# Project Euler 100 - can't understand solution

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations, project-euler

[Problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=100)

I solved this using OEIS (finding smaller values and then searching OEIS for related sequences, it turned out that the exact sequence I needed was there) [sequence](http://oeis.org/A011900).

Looking at the thread, the only solution that explained this was:

I did this one by hand, $b = \text{number of blue elements}$, $t = \text{total elements} $

$$
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{t^2 - t}{b^2 - b} &= 2\\
 t^2 - 2b^2 &= t - 2b
\end{aligned}
$$

But if $t = pn$ and $b = pk$ and $p = 2b - t$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
p^2n^2 - 2p^2b^2 = pt - 2pt = -p(2b - t) &= -p^2\\
 n^2 - 2b^2 &= -1 
\end{aligned}
$$

That is a diophantine equation, and its easy to get some solutions, I took the first solution where $pn = (2b - t)t > 10^{12}$: $n = 1607521$, $k = 1136689$

Everything here makes sense, however, I don't I understand how he came up with the idea to express $t$ as $p  n$ and $b$ as $p k$ (My guess is that $p$ is GCD of $b$ and $t$) And I definitely don't understand why he made $p = 2b - t$ (the only relation I can see to the equation is that it's the negative of the RHS, however I don't see how this is useful as a value of $p$, and seems quite arbitrary to me)

Comment: The original layout was extremely confusing due to equations being run together.  A later editor compounded the problem by adding LaTeX markup without consideration for the sense of the mathematics.  I have added breaks where I think they should be, but please check carefully.  Typos may remain, because there are a number of things that still make no sense.

Comment: It appears that the solution you refer to reduces the problem to that of solving a negative Pell equation.  This can be more simply done by completing the square in the equation $t(t-1)=2b(b-1)$ and clearing denominators.

Comment: I suggest the following corrections, but I leave it up to you: "But if $t = pn$ and $b = pk$ and $p = 2k - n$: 
$$
\begin{aligned}
p^2n^2 - 2p^2k^2 = pn - 2pk = -p(2k - n) &= -p^2\\
 n^2 - 2k^2 &= -1 
\end{aligned}
$$
That is a diophantine equation, and its easy to get some solutions, I took the first solution where $pn = (2k - n)n > 10^{12}$: $n = 1607521$, $k = 1136689$"

Comment: Looking at the thread post, it seems that the current version is correct. But thank you for correcting the formatting.

Comment: It would be helpful to add a link to the thread in your post.  I wasn't sure where to look for it.  There must be some mistake in the original thread because $pt-2pt=-p(2b-t)$ implies $b=t$, which I don't think is intended.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279317/sum-of-two-consecutive-squares-equals-difference-of-two-consecutive-cubes/279390#279390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very serious problems with the material you quote.  The second equality in the first line of
$$
\begin{aligned}
p^2n^2 - 2p^2b^2 = pt - 2pt = -p(2b - t) &= -p^2\\
 n^2 - 2b^2 &= -1 
\end{aligned}
$$
is surely wrong since it implies $b=t$, which forces $b=t=1$.  Replacing $pt-2pt$ with $pt-2pb$ might make sense, but it would still be unclear where the first equality, $p^2n^2 - 2p^2b^2 = pt - 2pb$, comes from.  Rather, it seems likely that the first equality is supposed to be $p^2n^2 - 2p^2k^2 = pt - 2pk$, since that follows immediately from $t^2-2b^2=t-2b$ by replacing $t$ with $pn$ and $b$ with $pk$.  Assuming this, we get
$$
p^2n^2 - 2p^2k^2 = pn - 2pk = -p(2k - n),
$$
but it is no longer true that this equals $-p^2$ unless the condition $p=2k-n$ is imposed instead of $p=2b-t$.  If we do this, we get $n^2-2k^2=-1$ instead of $n^2-2b^2=-1$.  This actually may be what the author intended because the given solution, $n=1607521$, $k=1136689$, does indeed satisfy $n^2-2k^2=-1$.  Furthermore, if $p=2k-n$ is used to calculate $p$ and $t=pn$, $b=pk$ are used to calculate $t$ and $b$, we do get the correct answer to the original question.

So it seems reasonable to revise the quoted passage as follows:

> But if $t=pn$ and $b=pk$ and $p=2k−n$:
>   $$
> \begin{aligned} p^2n^2 - 2p^2k^2 = pn - 2pk = -p(2k - n) &= -p^2\\  n^2 - 2k^2 &= -1  \end{aligned}
> $$
>   That is a diophantine equation, and its easy to get some solutions, I took the first solution where $pn=(2k−n)n>10^{12}$: $n=1607521$, $k=1136689$

The question them is: What justifies the assumption $p=2k-n$?  In fact, as will be shown below, $p$ takes one of two possible forms, $p=2k-n$ or $p=\frac{1}{2}(2k-n)$, depending on whether $n$ is odd or even.  Both possibilities have to be considered since there is no *a priori* reason why the answer to the original question should be one for which $n$ is odd.  It seems possible that the author of the quoted passage was simply lucky in assuming that $p=2k-n$.  Incidentally, you are correct in your surmise that $p=\gcd(t,b)$.

Here's the proof of the claim that $p=2k-n$ or $p=\frac{1}{2}(2k-n)$.  Let $(t,b)$ be a solution in positive integers to $2b^2-t^2=2b-t$.  One can readily show that $b\le t<2b$.  Compute $p=\gcd(t,b)$ and let $b=pk$ and $t=pn$ so that $\gcd(n,k)=1$.  Then $(2k^2-n^2)p=2k-n$.

Now $2k^2-n^2$ divides $2k-n$ and so $2k^2-n^2=\pm\gcd(2k^2-n^2,2k-n)$.  Because $2k-n$ and hence $2k^2-n^2$ is positive, the sign will be positive.  We now compute the needed GCD:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\gcd(2k^2-n^2,2k-n)&=\gcd(2k-n,2k^2-n^2-k(2k-n))\\
&=\gcd(2k-n,n^2-nk)\\
&=\gcd(2k-n,n(n-k)).
\end{aligned}
$$
If $n$ is odd, then $\gcd(2k-n,n)=\gcd(2k,n)=1$ so that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\gcd(2k^2-n^2,2k-n)&=\gcd(2k-n,n-k)\\
&=\gcd(n-k,k)=\gcd(n,k)=1.
\end{aligned}
$$
We conclude that $2k^2-n^2=1$.  This is a negative Pell equation.  In this case $p=2k-n$.

If $n=2r$ is even, so that $\gcd(2k-n,n)=\gcd(2(k-r),2r)=2$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\gcd(2k^2-n^2,2k-n)&=\gcd(2(k-r),2r(2r-k))\\
&=2\gcd(k-r,2r-k)=2\gcd(k-r,r)=2\gcd(k,r)=2.
\end{aligned}
$$
We conclude that $2k^2-n^2=2$.  This is the case that the author of the quoted passage appears to have missed.  Solutions are obtained from solutions to a Pell equation, $k^2-2r^2=1$.  In this case $p=\frac{1}{2}(2k-n)=k-r$.

There is another way to relate the original problem to a negative Pell equation, which is simpler, but doesn't provide the common factor of $t$ and $b$.  Complete the square:
$$
\begin{aligned}
t^2-t&=2(b^2-b)\\
(t-1/2)^2+1/4&=2(b-1/2)^2\\
(2t-1)^2+1&=2(2b-1)^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now look for pairs of odd numbers, $(x,y)$, that are solutions to the negative Pell equation $x^2-2y^2=-1$, and then take $t=(x+1)/2$, $b=(y+1)/2$.